# " character is not getting typed in my auto-typer program

Tags: java, keypress, awtrobot

This program reads from a file and types its contents out line by line or at the ends of sentences depending on config settings. It uses `Java.awt.Robot` to do this, and all the keyboard characters can be typed except the apostrophe and quotation characters. The key is function on my keyboard and other scripts can type it. I can't figure out why this program cannot type it correctly.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class SmartRobot extends Robot {

    public int count70=0;

 public SmartRobot() throws AWTException {
  super();
 }

 public void keyType(int keyCode) {
 if(keyCode == -1)
     return;
  keyPress(keyCode);
  delay(2);
  keyRelease(keyCode);
 }

 public void keyType(int keyCode, int keyCodeModifier) {
  keyPress(keyCodeModifier);
  keyPress(keyCode);
  delay(2);
  keyRelease(keyCode);
  keyRelease(keyCodeModifier);
 }


 public void type(String text) {
     if(text.length()>1 && text.substring(0, 1).equals("\\")){
         Driver.codeTimeEnd = System.nanoTime();
          delay(Integer.parseInt(text.substring(2, text.length()))-(int) (Driver.codeTimeEnd-Driver.codeTimeStart)/1000000000);
      return;
     }
  String textUpper = text.toUpperCase();
  for (int i=0; i<text.length(); ++i) {
   typeChar(textUpper.charAt(i));
  }  
  if(!Driver.enterAtPeriods || !Driver.enterUnder60)keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  Driver.codeTimeEnd =  System.nanoTime();
  if(!Driver.enterUnder60)
      delay(Driver.lineDelay-(int)(Driver.codeTimeEnd-    Driver.codeTimeStart)/1000000000);
  else
      delay(2);
 }

 public void typeChar(char c) {
  boolean shift = true;
  int keyCode;

  switch (c) {
  case '~':keyCode = (int)'`';break;
  case '!':keyCode = (int)'1';break;
  case '@':keyCode = (int)'2';break;
  case '#':keyCode = (int)'3';break;
  case '$':keyCode = (int)'4';break;
  case '%':keyCode = (int)'5';break;
  case '^':keyCode = (int)'6';break;
  case '&':keyCode = (int)'7';break;
  case '*':keyCode = (int)'8';break;
  case '(':keyCode = (int)'9';break;
  case ')':keyCode = (int)'0';break;
  case ':':keyCode = (int)';';break;
  case '_':keyCode = (int)'-';break;
  case '+':keyCode = (int)'=';break;
  case '|':keyCode = (int)'\\';break;
  case '"':keyCode = (int)'\'';break;
  case '?':keyCode = (int)'/';break;
  case '{':keyCode = (int)'[';break;
  case '}':keyCode = (int)']'; break;
  case '<':keyCode = (int)',';break;
  case '>':keyCode = (int)'.';break; 
  case '“':keyCode = (int)'\'';break;
  case '”':keyCode = (int)'\'';break;
  case '…':keyCode = (int)' ';break;
  case '‘':keyCode = (int)'\'';break;
  case '’':keyCode = (int)'\'';break;
 default:
//  System.out.println(c);
   keyCode = (int)c;
//   System.out.println(keyCode);
   shift = false;
  }
  if(Driver.enterUnder60){
      count70++;
      if(count70>70)
          if(c == ' '){
              count70 = 0;
              keyType(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
              delay(Driver.lineDelay-(int)(Driver.codeTimeEnd-Driver.codeTimeStart)/1000000000);
              return;
          }
  }
  if(Driver.enterAtPeriods){
      if(c == '.'){
          count70 = 0;
          keyType(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
          delay(Driver.lineDelay-(int)(Driver.codeTimeEnd-Driver.codeTimeStart)/1000000000);
          return;
      }
 }
  if (shift){
   keyType(keyCode, KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
   System.out.println("works");
  }
  else
   keyType(keyCode);
 }

 private int charToKeyCode(char c) {
  switch (c) {
  case ':':
   return ';';
  }
  return (int)c;
 }
}
```

The infile can be whatever you want it to be, and all characters will be shown, but the " will not be typed. I don't know if the `type()` method is ever accessed in its case.
Here is an example input:

```
"Hi, my name is koikoi."
```

The output comes out like this:

```
Hi, my name is koikoi.
```

When it should have the quotations on it. The typer does not recognize/read them. I can't find any flaws in my code and would like some advice. I can add the main method if requested.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your problem statement. Can you show some example inputs and outputs (wrong as well as expected)? Maybe then it gets clearer. Thanks.